# When I change values for a widget in flutter it does not update the widget

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, dart, widget, updates

I have tried to do hot restarts and stopping and rerunning the program but nothing updates on the virtual machine, the only thing that updates the program is debugging it. Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: const Text('data'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          width: 50,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.green,
          child: const Text('Points'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am new to flutter so it is probably a beginners error.

Comment: The code looks okay. I hope you use VS Code. Are you using Android emulator? Were you able to connect the emulator with VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command:

```
flutter clear
```

in the terminal and then try to rebuild the application in the code editor.

Even if that is the case try using your own android device.
And even if you get the same output you can try to run the application in chrome.

Comment: Sadly it did not work for me. I come from python without all the compiling.

Comment: Or please clear the emulator and create a new one.

Comment: It was me being stupid and not saving before running it.